# VirtualBox: Can't ping MS SQL Server guest from Ubuntu host

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect the guest to the local network so I can ping it and my application can send db requests to it. I am on a laptop which seems to be part of the problem because it only has a wireless adapter. My current settings on VirtualBox use Bridged Adapter, which has already worked in the past but sometimes stops doing so when I connect to a different wireless network. I don't need an internet connection on the guest, I just need to be able to connect to it on the local network, so if any other networking setting works that'd be fine. The ideal setting would allow me to work even when not connected to any wireless network.

```
Host: Ubuntu 16.04
Guest: MS SQL Server 2008 R2
```

When I tried setting the IP automatically I got from `ipconfig` on the guest:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 169.254.54.69
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway:
```

Previously I had set it to a fixed IP address which resulted in:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.7
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway:
```

This one used to work until I changed to a different wireless network.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAT for the Guest. And forward the Ports from the Guest to the Host.

Referencing to this:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html